# Getting python console to flash in Windows taskbar

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I am attempting to cause my python application to flash its parent console's icon in the taskbar. I have tried the following:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.FlashWindow(
ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), True)
```

and

```
ctypes.windll.user32.FlashWindow(
ctypes.windll.user32.GetParent(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()), True)
```

But neither of these cause the desired effect.

I am using python 3.5.4, on Windows 10. I am using cmder as my console.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182796/python-ctypes-issue-on-different-oses/53185316#53185316, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268294/python-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrary-instantiate-an-object-execute-its-method-priva/52272969#52272969. **Define *argtypes* and *restype* for the 2 functions**.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FlashWindowEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex) to specifically flash just the taskbar icon. For a regular console window, get the window handle via `GetConsoleWindow`. This may not work for alternative consoles such as ConEmu, unless it's one of the API functions that they hack.

For example:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

FLASHW_STOP = 0
FLASHW_CAPTION = 0x00000001
FLASHW_TRAY = 0x00000002
FLASHW_ALL = 0x00000003
FLASHW_TIMER = 0x00000004
FLASHW_TIMERNOFG = 0x0000000C

class FLASHWINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('cbSize', wintypes.UINT),
                ('hwnd', wintypes.HWND),
                ('dwFlags', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('uCount', wintypes.UINT),
                ('dwTimeout', wintypes.DWORD))
    def __init__(self, hwnd, flags=FLASHW_TRAY, count=5, timeout_ms=0):
        self.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        self.hwnd = hwnd
        self.dwFlags = flags
        self.uCount = count
        self.dwTimeout = timeout_ms

kernel32.GetConsoleWindow.restype = wintypes.HWND
user32.FlashWindowEx.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(FLASHWINFO),)

def flash_console_icon(count=5):
    hwnd = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
    if not hwnd:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    winfo = FLASHWINFO(hwnd, count=count)
    previous_state = user32.FlashWindowEx(ctypes.byref(winfo))
    return previous_state
```