# Passing audio data from Python to C with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a C++ library which performs analysis on audio data, and a C API to it. One of the C API functions takes `const int16_t*` pointers to the data and returns the results of the analysis.

I'm trying to build a Python interface to this API, and most of it is working, but I'm having trouble getting ctypes pointers to use as arguments for this function. Since the pointers on the C side are to `const`, it feels to me like it ought to be possible to make this work fine with any contiguous data. However, the following does not work:

```py
import ctypes
import wave

_native_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libsound.so')
_native_function = _native_lib.process_sound_data
_native_function.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16),
                             ctypes.c_size_t]
_native_function.restype = ctypes.c_int

wav_path = 'hello.wav'

with wave.open(wav_path, mode='rb') as wav_file:
    wav_bytes = wav_file.readframes(wav_file.getnframes())

data_start = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16).from_buffer(wav_bytes) # ERROR: data is immutable
_native_function(data_start, len(wav_bytes)//2)
```

Manually copying `wav_bytes` to a `bytearray` allows the pointer to be constructed but causes the native code to segfault, indicating that the address it receives is wrong (it passes unit tests with data read in from C++). Fixing this by getting the address right would technically solve the problem but I feel like there's a better way.

Surely it's possible to just get the address of some data and promise that it's the right format and won't be altered? I'd prefer not to have to deep copy all my Pythonically-stored audio data to a ctypes format, since presumably the bytes are in there somewhere if I can just get a pointer to them!

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this

```py
data_start = cast_to(address_of(data[0]), c_int16_pointer)
_native_function(data_start, len(data))
```

which would then work with anything that has a `[0]` and a `len`. Is there a way to do something like this in ctypes? If not, is there a technical reason why it's impossible, and is there something else I should be using instead?

Comment: Specify *argtypes* and *restype* for *\_native\_function*. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268294/python-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrary-instantiate-an-object-execute-its-method-priva/52272969#52272969
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182796/python-ctypes-issue-on-different-oses/53185316#53185316.

Comment: @CristiFati I edited in the code loading `_native_function`. My question is not how to declare this function, but rather how to convert Python data into a suitable argument for it.

Comment: Your comment about the segfaulting is interesting.  Did you see this in Windows?  Did you try it under macOS or Linux?  I feel a [question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64421004/562930) could be associated to what your saw.

Comment: @MatthewWalker Unfortunately I only tested this on Linux so I have no idea what would happen on Windows. Actually, I don't think I ever fixed that dodgy copy on Linux either since I ended up just casting it instead. The whole ctypes API is a bit of a mess to be honest. And I'm afraid I don't know how you could debug your issue short of compiling your own CPython with -g and running GDB on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.  Use `array` for a writable buffer and create a ctypes array that references the buffer.

```
data = array.array('h',wav_bytes)
addr,size = data.buffer_info()
arr = (c_short * size).from_address(addr)
_native_function(arr,size)
```

Alternatively, to skip the copy of `wav_bytes` into `data` array, you could lie about the pointer type in argtypes.  `ctypes` knows how convert a byte string to a `c_char_p`.  A pointer is just an address, so the `_native_function` will receive the address but use it as an `int*` internally:

```
_native_function.argtypes = c_char_p,c_size_t
_native_function(wav_bytes,len(wav_bytes) // 2)
```

Another way to work around the "underlying buffer is not writable" error  is to leverage `c_char_p`, which allows an immutable byte string to used, and then explicitly cast it to the pointer type you want:

```
_native_function.argtypes = POINTER(c_short),c_size_t
p = cast(c_char_p(wav_bytes),POINTER(c_short))
_native_function(p,len(wav_bytes) // 2)
```

In these latter cases you must ensure you don't actually write to the buffer as it will corrupt the immutable Python object holding the data.

Comment: From looking at the documentation this seems to deep copy the data into an array. I agree that it should work, but I'm looking for a way to pass this existing data into the C functions without copying all of it (or an explanation of why it's fundamentally impossible to do this).

Comment: @BaryonsforBreakfast.  There is a way.  See update above.

Comment: @BaryonsforBreakfast Added another option as well.

Comment: I just had a chance to test the third method and it does seem to work (as it obviously should). It's a bit less flexible and a bit less safe than I'd like but it's probably the best that can be done as long as ctypes doesn't have `const`. Thanks!

Comment: For the third example, does `c_char_p` not [assume the string is NULL terminated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p)?  So for the likes of audio data, which may contain NULLs throughout, would that not potentially create an issue?  Further, it's plausible that audio data is not NULL terminated--it would depend on the audio itself.  Do you still feel `c_char_p` is an option here?

Comment: @MatthewWalker No it just passes an address to C. The buffer can contain anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MarkTolonen.  It worries me that the documentation says "For a general character pointer that may also point to binary data, POINTER(c_char) must be used."

Comment: @MatthewWalker `ctypes` does have special handling if you use `c_char_p` as a return type.  It gets converted to a Python `bytes` string only up to a null pointer and loses access to the pointer value.  If you call a C function that allocates memory and still need access to the pointer, or the returned pointer is arbitrary binary data, *then* you need `POINTER(c_char)`.  It's also possible to suppress the `c_char_p` default behavior by deriving a subclass, e.g. `class LPCHAR(c_char_p): pass`.

Comment: @MatthewWalker It talks about my above comment behavior in the the [Fundamental Data Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-fundamental-data-types-2) paragraphs.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, that's very clear, thanks.  It's a pity the official documentation is not as specific.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look around at the CPython bug tracker to see if this had come up before, and it seems it was [raised as an issue in 2011](https://bugs.python.org/issue11427). I agree with the poster that it's a serious mis-design, but it seems the developers at that time did not.

Eryk Sun's comment on that thread revealed that it's actually possible to just use `ctypes.cast` directly. Here is part of the comment:

> `cast` calls `ctypes._cast(obj, obj, typ)`. `_cast` is a ctypes function pointer defined as follows:
>
> ```
>    _cast = PYFUNCTYPE(py_object, 
>                       c_void_p, py_object, py_object)(_cast_addr)
> ```
>
> Since `cast` makes an FFI call that converts the first arg to `c_void_p`, you can directly cast `bytes` to a pointer type:
>
> ```
>    >>> from ctypes import *
>    >>> data = b'123\x00abc'
>
>    >>> ptr = cast(data, c_void_p)
> ```

It's a bit unclear to me if this is actually required by the standard or if it's just a CPython implementation detail, but the following works for me in CPython:

```py
import ctypes
data = b'imagine this string is 16-bit sound data'
data_ptr = ctypes.cast(data, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16))
```

The [documentation on `cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast) says the following:

> `ctypes.cast(obj, type)`
>
> This function is similar to the cast operator in C. It returns a new instance of type which points to the same memory block as obj. type must be a pointer type, and obj must be an object that can be interpreted as a pointer.

so it seems that that CPython is of the opinion that `bytes` 'can be interpreted as a pointer'. This seems fishy to me, but these modern pointer-hiding languages have a way of messing with my intuition.

Comment: However, at least under Python 3.8, it seems that a `memoryview` cannot be cast.  If we continue on with your example above, `mv = memoryview(data); data_ptr = ctypes.cast(mv, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16))` generates the error `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`.  Any ideas for working around this issue?

Comment: @MatthewWalker I've never used `memoryview` before but looking at the documentation it seems that even though it *sounds* like a simple `char*` pointer and a length, the data they point to doesn't actually have to be contiguous, so it's actually more like a pair of C++ iterators. I would guess that you can't cast it due to some combination of (a) the data may not be contiguous [though they could check and raise an exception], and (b) no one has bothered to write a conversion for it.