# How to debug access violation memory issues in Python under Windows?

Tags: python, memory, ctypes

What tools or processes would you recommend for debugging ctypes memory issues?  How is it possible to print the contents of an array but not be able to copy it?

I have narrowed my problem down to the following lines:

```
   [ ... lots of code ...]

   valid_data_as_bytes = bytearray(self._output_buffer[:result])
   print("valid_data_as_bytes:",valid_data_as_bytes)
   print("len(valid_data_as_bytes):", len(valid_data_as_bytes))
   assert len(valid_data_as_bytes) == result
   Buffer = ctypes.c_ubyte * len(valid_data_as_bytes)
   buf2 = Buffer.from_buffer_copy(valid_data_as_bytes)  # <--- error occurs here

   [ ... lots of code ...]
```

Below is a print out of the last few lines of output when the tests are run with the command `pytest -s`:

```
valid_data_as_bytes: bytearray(b'\xfc\xdf]\'O\xb6\xf4n\xa3p\x87\xcd\xca\xe1\xd53~V\x04\xa3\x977\xd3q[\xf8\x9dh\xe1\x05\x7f\xf3$\xb2S,\xa4\x8d\x04\xe6\xc0\x12\xbf)\xb8\r\xcb&\x9a(\x08\x1c\xca\x1a\x13\x16\xba}\x93e\xf0J\x91\x8eJ\xcbk\xc0\xc2\xc9@{\xcc$\x7f\x1d0\xc58\xcf\xe5\xbf_W\r\x02\xf7\xb8\x7fm\xa1\xd9\xa8\xba6\xed\x17\xdf;\x7f\x8b\x9a\x9f\x03\r\xec\xdc]\x14\xfd\x15B\x98\\\xcb\xc8)\xdd9\xc0\xb2\xb5\xa5Af\x85\x8b\x1a\xac\x89,#\xd9 \xc7\x86SiE|\x84B\xdc"\xcfhG\xef\xec\xffh\x84\x14\xdb\xf9\xc9J2O\xe3[8\x9531Be\xb0p\x87\x0eJ\xa4i\xce)\xbaBXY\xdeP\x88\x13\xdc](_\xd5^m\xdc\xde\x18\x13\xb2H\xe0\xae\xea=#+\x92\xd3\xe6[W\x94X\x96\xfe\xa3\x137\xe9\xfe\xcc6F\xb9\x0b\xc3NO\x93Ksy\xc4A\xcb"\xf0\xc1\xa0\x83\xa3\xc4@\xbb\\\xb8\xfd\xbem\'(A\x9f\x0fV\x9f\xe1\xc0\x97\xd0\x95W"a\x94\xfdymv\xa2>P\x9d\xcc\x80\xc13B\xd0\nu\xd4\x04\xa9\xc4\xd3\xb5q3\x8f\x08:\xacrm\x1bre\x0e\x9a\xd5\x98\xeez \xd3H\xd2\xed\xdd\x12\xd8\xa2,[\xac\xdf\x13\x9f\xed\xa8\xf5\x98\x97\xb3\xc4\x10\xc3\xa6\x10A\x96.>D\x048\x02~\x9c}\xa5\xd1\x93\xd0I\xe94\x1b\x85\'~0\x92\x82lr')
len(valid_data_as_bytes): 354
Windows fatal exception: access violation
```

This code does not error under macOS or Linux.  It also does not error when each of the pytest-based tests in the test suite are run individually.  However it consistently throws a `Windows fatal exception: access violation` error when the entire test suite is run.

I have been looking at [what I believe is the implementation of `from_buffer_copy()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/155938907c2b3df71608ddeaa0a43d2ec1f2c699/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L670-L713), however I do not know how to step through this; what tools would be best to step through the C-side of Python after it has been running many tests?  Or perhaps I should be looking elsewhere?

There are no threads or processes other than the main thread.

On the fact that the code in inefficient: in an attempt to pin down this issue, I forced Python to copy all blocks of memory (hence, for example, the bytearray conversion).

Any suggestions would be very gratefully received!

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions) is helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @BrenBarn.  From that section of the ctypes documentation I felt the most useful information was on `faulthandler`, which is how I can say where the error is occurring.  Other than that, the call to `from_buffer_copy()` is internal to Python and so not a ctypes function call.  Unless I missed something else you were referring to?

Comment: Well, it is a method on a ctypes type, so it is basically a ctypes function.  But yes, I was mostly thinking the faulthandler info might be useful.

Comment: I copyied your bytearray, created Buffer and assigned buf2 and it worked without error.  Can't reproduce.

Comment: Hi @MarkTolonen.  Yes, you're entirely correct.  It does not cause an error when the tests are run independently.  If I run each test one after the other, no errors occur.  However if I run the entire test suite, then the error occurs.  This is reproducible on the AWS Windows Server and using Travis CI (via GitHub).  If you're feeling like you have the time to investigate, I'd be *extremely* happy to point you to the GitHub repository.

Comment: Sounds like some other portion of the tests corrupts memory...the worst bug to debug

Comment: @MarkTolonen Getting somewhere! Thanks to your suggestion, I looked into the minimum configuration of tests that cause the error.  I'm down to having zero tests before the test-that-errors, and only one import statement.  So the issue stems from the package having already been imported... Many thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Should anybody be reading this, I found that even the import (discussed in my previous comment) wasn't necessary.  All that's required to generate an error is to have one file that pytest detects as a test before the test in question.  That one file can be utterly empty.  I am--to state it mildly--confused.

Comment: @MatthewWalker, have you found the cause of the 'access violation'? If so, please share your findings as I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: It's been two years, so the best I can offer is a blog post I wrote while trying to debug this: https://mattgwwalker.wordpress.com/2020/10/15/address-of-a-buffer-in-python/

This post might also help: https://mattgwwalker.wordpress.com/2020/05/30/pointer-manipulation-in-python/