# Resultpointer in function call

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to use functions in dll's via ctype. I can call the function without errors and even the error code of the function is 0 meanig function successfuly finished. But when I try to acces the result variable ist is empty.

I have been implemented the lookup in free pascal severeal years ago and would transfer it to python right now. The interface allow to access via cdel convention and I tied to reimplement in python 3.7.4 with ctypes now

The last working Pascal Prototype have been:

```pascal
PROCEDURE pGetCallInfo(DriveInfo: pointer; ACall: pointer; AInfo: pointer;
    var AErrorCode: SmallInt); pascal; external 'raccd32a.dll';
```

My best version in python have been the following:

```py
from ctypes import *
callBookDLL = CDLL('raccd32a')
AInfo = create_string_buffer(400)
err = callBookDLL.cGetCallInfo("self.txt_CallBookPath.text()","DG1ATN",AInfo)
```

The result ist:

err 
0
AInfo.value
b''

AInfo should contain a max. 400 char long stringbuffer with an result containing Name, Adress and so on.

As I have a second library I have to acces same way I search for my fault but I was not able to find it. I think my problem is the work with pointer and the type conversion.

I checked teh ctypes howto allready but I can noht solve this trouble.

Thanks a lot so far ...

Comment: How does the function declaration look like in *C*? *ctypes* doesn't support *pascal* calling convention (assuming your *.dll* is *32bit*).

Comment: I never uses the function in C, I think that is even my problem to convert the function. As well as I did not understand the Manual in that case. They did not give a header file they try to explain.
I put the explanations on my server, to be found at http://awi5.maschinenbau.tu-ilmenau.de/RACCD32a.txt
Thanks so far ...

Comment: I'd suggest to edit your question  and add all the required details (for example how do you call the function from *Delphi*). Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). It contains (almost) every piece of info that you need.

There are a number of problems:

1. *ctypes* doesn't support *pascal* calling convention, only *cdecl* and *stdcall* (applies to *32bit* only). That means (after reading the manual) that you shouldn't use the *p** functions, but the *c** (or *s**)
2. You didn't specify *argtypes* (and *restype*) for your function. This results in *UB*. Some effects of this:

   - [[SO]: Python ctypes cdll.LoadLibrary, instantiate an object, execute its method, private variable address truncated (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268294/python-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrary-instantiate-an-object-execute-its-method-priva/52272969#52272969)
   - [[SO]: python ctypes issue on different OSes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182796/python-ctypes-issue-on-different-oses/53185316#53185316)
3. It is a procedure (a function that returns *void*). Anyway this is a minor one

Here's some sample code (of course it's blind, as I didn't test it):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes


dll = ctypes.CDLL("raccd32a.dll")

cGetCallInfo = dll.cGetCallInfo
cGetCallInfo.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_short)]
cGetCallInfo.restype = None

ADriveInfo = self.txt_CallBookPath.text().encode()
#ADriveInfo = b"C:\\callbook2019\\"  # Notice the double bkslashes
ACall = b"DG1ATN"
AInfo = ctypes.create_string_buffer(400)
result = ctypes.c_short(0)
cGetCallInfo(ADriveInfo, ACall, AInfo, ctypes.byref(result))
```

***@EDIT0***:

From the beginning, I wanted yo say that the 1<sup>st</sup> argument passed to the function doesn't make much sense. Then, there are problems regarding the 2<sup>nd</sup> one as well. According to the manual ([[AMT-I]: TECHNICAL INFORMATION about RACCD32a.DLL](http://awi5.maschinenbau.tu-ilmenau.de/RACCD32a.txt) (**emphasis** is mine)):

> ADriveInfo, ACall and AInfo are pointers to zero-terminated strings. These
>   strings has to exist at the moment of calling xGetCallInfo. The calling
>   program is responsible for creating them. AInfo must be long enough to
>   comfort xGetCallInfo (at least 400 characters).
>   Note: "Length of AInfo" refers to the length of the string AInfo points at.
>   ADriveInfo and ACall are treated in the same manner for short.
>
> **In ADriveInfo the procedure expects the path to the CD ROM drive. Use
>     "G:\"
>   if "G:" designates the CD ROM drive with the callbook CD ROM**.
>   Keep in mind that this information is a *must* and the calling program
>   has to know it.
>   Note: If the active directory on drive G: is not the root, ADriveInfo = "G:"
>   will lead to an error 3. So always use "G:\".
>   The calling program has to ensure that the length of ADriveInfo does not
>   exceed 80 characters.
>
> **ACall contains the call you are looking for, all letters in lower case**,
>   no additional spaces etc. The calling program has to ensure that ACall is
>   not longer than 15 characters. However, there is no call longer than 6
>   characters in the database.

Comment: Thanks, It looks better but I get another error code now. I have to check with other data cd first but I could not understand why it works with pascal and this dll an not with python. I get error code **-3: Wrong CD: DLL does not match the CD inserted- ask for a new DLL** now. If I cange the path (parameter 1), then I got error code **3: Path not found** so it look like the parameter will be ok. I check an it have been the dll version deliverd with the used CD.

Comment: And one more question, why AInfo had not been marked as ctypes.byref()? The content of this variable should also be changed by the dll?

Comment: The buffer is mutable (it's in the link I provided).

Comment: What happens if from pascal you use `PROCEDURE cGetCallInfo(DriveInfo: pointer; ACall: pointer; AInfo: pointer;
    var AErrorCode: SmallInt); cdecl; external 'raccd32a.dll';`?

Comment: I am on vacation right now and I will answer tonight. But I did not have a pascal IDE or Debugger installed on this Laptop. I will send you how I use the result from the code an I know that the Software had been working in July last time. As I have to integrate new functionality and I had to use python at work I started a  redesign during my holiday trip.

Comment: I just checked the Pascal code. There I only evaluate the error code. I am currently only interested in whether ACall is present in the database or not. 
Here the code excerpt: 
<code>    
pGetCallInfo({at}DriveInfo, {at}Call, {at}Info, ErrorCode);
    if ErrorCode > 0 then
        memo1.Lines.Add(format('%-20s => %d',[strs[i],ErrorCode]));
    if (ErrorCode = 0)  then 
        do something, 
</code>
And with DG1ATN oder EF1W I got 0 and now I got -3

Comment: I chech with the seconde dll (uses stdcall and it works perfect, I will contact the autor off the first and check if there is a problem with the dll. When I got the answer I will come back to this tread and close or ask again

Comment: The first argument was an qt5 lineEdit field where I had my local path in ...it has a length of 62 char. I use it with **self.txt_CallBookPath.text().encode()** ... perhaps the hint was good, because i might remember that ther is no whitespace allowed, but it still not work, The ACall normaly came from a mysql request so I use my own call DG1ATN only for testting and discribing. For the last test I used as ADriveInfo b"C:\callbook2019\"

Comment: I'd suggest (as I commented on the question) to put all relevant info in the question, instead of scattering it in comments.

Comment: I tried again @home and your solution works perfect. I think the database should not be on drive c: it works on drive h: (Networkdrive)