# Ctypes- Can't get PEB Address using NtQueryInformationProcess

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, ctypes

I am using `ctypes` and trying to get the `PEB` address using the `NtQueryInformationProcess` function.

The return value is 0, meaning that the function was completed successfully. 
But the `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure (given as the third argument) doesn't contain the `PEB` address.

```
class PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("Reserved1", c_void_p),
        ("PebBaseAddress", DWORD),
        ("Reserved2", c_void_p * 2),
        ("UniqueProcessId", DWORD),
        ("Reserved3", c_void_p)]

ntdll = WinDLL('ntdll')
NTSTATUS = LONG
ntdll.argtypes = [HANDLE, DWORD, c_void_p, DWORD, PDWORD]
ntdll.restype = NTSTATUS
processInformation = PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION()
processInformationLength = sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION)
result = ntdll.NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, 0, processInformation, processInformationLength, byref(DWORD(0)))
```

Consider the fact that the return value is 0, what can be the problem?

Comment: What does the PEB field contain after the function returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

1. You defined *argtypes* and *restype* for the **wrong** object (*ntdll*). You should define them for `ntdll.NtQueryInformationProcess`. While we are here, it's obvious that you like *DWORD*. Even if in this case it makes no difference, keep function signatures consistent with the ones from *C*:

   ```py
   ntdll.NtQueryInformationProcess.argtypes = [HANDLE, c_int, c_void_p, ULONG, PULONG]
   ntdll.NtQueryInformationProcess.restype = NTSTATUS
   ```

   Failing to define *argtypes* and *restype* (or doing it incorrectly) on a function, an may (, and most likely will) lead to:

   - [[SO]: Python ctypes cdll.LoadLibrary, instantiate an object, execute its method, private variable address truncated (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268294/python-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrary-instantiate-an-object-execute-its-method-priva/52272969#52272969)
   - [[SO]: python ctypes issue on different OSes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182796/python-ctypes-issue-on-different-oses/53185316#53185316)
2. According to [[MS.Docs]: NtQueryInformationProcess function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess) (**emphasis** is mine):

   > `ProcessInformation`
   >
   > A **pointer** to a buffer supplied by the calling application into which the function writes the requested information.

   So, your call should look like (pass *processInformation* by reference):

   ```py
   result = ntdll.NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, 0, byref(processInformation), processInformationLength, byref(DWORD(0)))
   ```
3. According to the same page, your structure definition is incorrect. It should be:

   ```py
   class PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION(Structure):
       _fields_ = [
           ("Reserved1", c_void_p),
           ("PebBaseAddress", c_void_p),
           ("Reserved2", c_void_p * 2),
           ("UniqueProcessId", c_void_p),
           ("Reserved3", c_void_p),
       ]
   ```

   Your version (on *64bit*) is 8 bytes shorter (because of (the 2) size differences between *DWORD* and pointer), resulting in a too short buffer being passed to the function, which is ***U***ndefined **B**ehavior (it can lead to crashes).