# Import ctypes prevent importing other modules

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

some info about the system: win10 64-bit, python version 3.7.0 32-bit

I have a very strange issue with my Python code. I need to use some methods from a C++ 32 bit-DLL inside my python code. Importing and using DLL methods works fine with the module 'ctypes':

```
    from ctypes import*
    self.mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('okSbam.dll')
    self.mydll.loadlib(".")
```

Now, I need to use numpy and pyqtgraph inside the same application. By simply typing the classical 'import numpy as np' or 'import pyqtgraph as pg' leads to a very strange issue: my application simply does not load anymore, with no error shown on the shell:

```
    from ctypes import*
    import numpy as np
    self.mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('okSbam.dll')
    self.mydll.loadlib(".")
```

I've tried to look for similar issues, but in all cases there were some sort of error message to investigate.
Does any of you have had any similar problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `self.mydll.loadlib(".")` as it is, is incorrect (at least for 64bit). Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268294/python-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrary-instantiate-an-object-execute-its-method-priva/52272969#52272969 to see why (although for 32bit it isn't such a problem). What does *loadlib* do (how do you know it works the 1st time, but not the 2nd)? You should check its return value (if any) for errors.

Comment: Thank you. In my code, as the answer you report suggests, I correctly define restype and argtype. So I don't think my problem is there.

Comment: In this case you should format your question according to [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CristiFati , the one I posted is a mcve. I just didn't put all the remaining code with all GUI elements callbacks, which is not useful to solve my issue.

Comment: @CristiFati what do you mean with " **What does loadlib do (how do you know it works the 1st time, but not the 2nd)?**"

Comment: I meant what is that func supposed to do? And Based on what you decide that the app loads or doesn't?

Comment: The function loadlib is a DLL function that imports another DLL (inside the primary DLL). If, in my python code, I do not import numpy, my application loads properly and I can use well all my DLL C-functions. By simply importing numpy (no use of any numpy feature in the python code), my application does not load anymore, I.E. the GUI does not start without any error or warning. I am using IDLE and in the python shell i only see "RESTART: shell". Nothing more..

Comment: Do you have the code for *loadlib* (or at least its declaration)? Also, it loads a specific or any *.dll* at location given as an argument? What does it return? The lines of code didn't mention any *GUI*.What happens if you save the code ina file and call *Python* on it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not have access to the code for loadlib. However, I was able to solve my issue. Across all DLL imported functions, I just forgot (only for that one!!) to specify restype and argtypes for loadlib, that was the cause of the issue. Now I the program runs fine. Thank you @CristiFati for your patience :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! You might want to answer your question.