# ctypes.ArgumentError when using kivy with pywinauto

Tags: python, kivy, ctypes, pywinauto

I have a kivy application that can interact with other windows using the pywinauto module. The application works fine in Linux (where pywinauto isn't used) but in Windows I get the following error, the application won't even start up:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py:80: UserWarning: Revert to STA COM threading mode
    warnings.warn("Revert to STA COM threading mode", UserWarning)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\application.py", line 368, in <module>
    Application().run()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 826, in run
    runTouchApp()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 477, in runTouchApp
    EventLoop.start()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 164, in start
    provider.start()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_touch.py", line 68, in start
    self.hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, self.new_windProc)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

The reason I think it's an issue with pywinauto, is that I have the following lines and it works fine in Linux:

```
if SYSTEM == "Windows":
    import win32gui
    import win32process
    import wmi

    from pywinauto import application
    import pywinauto
```

Also I comment out the pywinauto import lines and it starts. It could be linked to [this issue.](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/419) I don't really know what code to include, as it works in other operating systems.... I'm assuming pywinauto is changing something that stops kivy from working.

My question is this: how can I have both the functionality of kivy and pywinauto in the same application?

Comment: Can you provide the sample Kivy app reproducing the problem?

Comment: try importing *pywinauto* before *kivy*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the behavior using:

- *Python 3.7.3 pc064*
- *Kivy 1.10.1*
- *PyWinAuto 0.6.6*

As a side note, I didn't work with any of the 2 packages before, I `pip install`ed them specifically for this task.

Since I had no idea how to reproduce the behavior, I just copied the *MCVE* from [[GitHub]: pywinauto/pywinauto - ctypes.ArgumentError @ click_input](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/419) (that you also shared in the question), and slightly modified it (only to hit the error, with little style improvements).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
import sys

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

import pywinauto  # @TODO - cfati: moved AFTER Kivy import(s), as it works otherwise (https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/419#issuecomment-488258224)


class DemoLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


Builder.load_string("""
#: import datetime  datetime.datetime
<DemoLayout>:
  padding: 75

  Button:
    on_press: print(f"PRESSED @ {datetime.now()}")
""")


class Demo(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = DemoLayout()


    def on_start(self):
        title = f"__KIVY_APP__{random.getrandbits(128)}"
        Window.set_title(title)
        hwnd = pywinauto.findwindows.find_window(title=title)
        app = pywinauto.Application()
        app.connect(handle=hwnd)
        window = app.window(handle=hwnd).wrapper_object()
        window.click_input(button="left", pressed="", coords=(100, 100), double=False, absolute=False)


def main(*argv):
    Demo().run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055928463]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\cfati\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-05-01_83.txt
> [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
> [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
> [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
> [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
> [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 - Build 23.20.16.4973'>
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 530'>
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 - Build 23.20.16.4973'>
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
> [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
> [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
> [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
>  e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py:80: UserWarning: Revert to STA COM threading mode
>    warnings.warn("Revert to STA COM threading mode", UserWarning)
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
> [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "code00.py", line 50, in <module>
>      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>    File "code00.py", line 44, in main
>      Demo().run()
>    File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 826, in run
>      runTouchApp()
>    File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 477, in runTouchApp
>      EventLoop.start()
>    File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 164, in start
>      provider.start()
>    File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_touch.py", line 68, in start
>      self.hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, self.new_windProc)
>  ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
> ```

Before going further, I want to point out:

1. [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)
2. [[MS.Learn]: SetWindowLongPtrW function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw)

As seen from the latter, *SetWindowLongPtrW*'s 3<sup>rd</sup> argument can be a *DWORD*, a *HANDLE*, a function pointer, depending on the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument value: basically it's a *void** that can be mapped to anything.
Both modules call this function via *CTypes*:

- *PyWinAuto* ([[GitHub]: pywinauto/pywinauto - (0.6.6) pywinauto/pywinauto/win32functions.py](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/0.6.6/pywinauto/win32functions.py)):

  ```py
  try:
      SetWindowLongPtr    =   ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW
      SetWindowLongPtr.argtypes = [win32structures.HWND, ctypes.c_int, win32structures.LONG_PTR]
      SetWindowLongPtr.restype = win32structures.LONG_PTR
  except AttributeError:
      SetWindowLongPtr = SetWindowLong
  ```
- *Kivy* ([[GitHub]: kivy/kivy - (1.10.1) kivy/kivy/input/providers/wm_common.py](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/1.10.1/kivy/input/providers/wm_common.py)):

  ```py
  try:
      windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW.restype = WNDPROC
      windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW.argtypes = [HANDLE, c_int, WNDPROC]
      SetWindowLong_wrapper = windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW
  except AttributeError:
      windll.user32.SetWindowLongW.restype = WNDPROC
      windll.user32.SetWindowLongW.argtypes = [HANDLE, c_int, WNDPROC]
      SetWindowLong_wrapper = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW
  ```

**Explanation**:

- *User32.dll* is only loaded once in the current *Python* process
- Code as above initializes the functions and typically is only executed once, at module import time (it can be executed as many times as desired, but it would decrease performance)
- Both modules specify the function (*windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW* as we are on *064bit*) prototype, but they do it **differently**
- From the 3 above, results that **the module that gets imported last, decides how the function prototype will look like**
- When the module that was imported 1<sup>st</sup> tries to use the prototype, **it doesn't match the arguments passed**, hence the error

That's why I had to move *PyWinAuto* import after *Kivy*, so that *Kivy* tried to call the function using *PyWinAuto*'s prototype, otherwise it would have worked.
It's possible to go the other way around, but I didn't bother to find a scenario where *PyWinAuto* would call the function, as it's not relevant.

Looking at the 2 *CTypes* prototypes and the *C* one (from *MS* *URL*), it turns out that:

- *PyWinAuto* is doing things correctly (I'm curious how it would work on *032bit*, though)
- *Kivy* only uses a *SetWindowLongPtrW* use-case (the one with the function pointer), and to make things easier, they adapted the prototype for their scenario. However, **it doesn't quite match the *C* prototype**, and this from my *PoV*, looks like a lame workaround (*gainarie*)

I modified my *Kivy* installation, and *tadaa*! (it's the Easter Bunny! :) ):

[image: Working]

Check:

- [[SO]: How to keep pynput and ctypes from clashing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53643273/4788546) for a simpler variant
- **[[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)** for a deeper and more generic analysis of this common (*CTypes* related) pitfall

---

#### Update *#0*

I've submitted **[[GitHub]: kivy/kivy - SetWindowLongPtrW ctypes prototype bug](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/6281)**, which **was merged on *190502***. Not sure when it will be available on the market ([PyPI](https://pypi.org), so you can simply `pip install` it), though.

As an alternative, you could download the patch, and apply the changes locally. Check [[SO]: Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *UTRunner*** section) for how to apply patches on *Win* (basically, every line that starts with **one "+"** sign goes in, and every line that starts with **one "-"** sign goes out).
Or you could download the 3 modified files and overwrite your existing ones.
In any case, **back them up** first! Also, I don't know how the changes fit into older *Kivy* versions.

Comment: Fixed by importing pywinauto before kivy. I guess I should have expected this since I've had problems with pywinauto and the wmi module before now, fixed in the same way.

Comment: @qr7NmUTjF6vbA4n8V3J9: That's fine too, but you realize it's just a workaround.